# Understanding Microsoft's _Is_duration using C++11 type_traits

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, metaprogramming, type-traits

I am still learning TMP and using `<type_traits>`. I was looking at Microsoft's implementation of `std::chrono::duration_cast<T>` and I am hoping someone can help me understand how their `_Is_duration` class template works. I appreciate the help.

```
template<class _Ty>
    struct _Is_duration
    {   // tests for duration
    static const bool value = false;
    };

// duration_cast
template<class _To,
    class _Rep,
    class _Period> inline
    typename enable_if<_Is_duration<_To>::value, _To>::type
        duration_cast(const duration<_Rep, _Period>& _Dur)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Presumably they specialize it for all durations.

Comment: Posting code of proprietary software is illegal... :)

Comment: @40two It's probably fair use :)

Comment: Sorry, I will remove it if it isn't allowed.

Comment: Relax dude, we were joking.

Comment: Oh ok, I was wondering if the sirens outside were for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not the full implementation. It's probably going to be partially specialized for `duration`s, something like:

```
template<class _Rep,
    class _Period>
    struct _Is_duration<duration<_Rep, _Period>>
    {   // tests for duration
    static const bool value = true;
    };
```

Thus, if you pass a `duration` as the type parameter, the partial specialization will be used and `value` == `true`, and otherwise the base template will be used, and `value` == `false`.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably just specialized for durations somewhere else in the code.

Comment: Indeed. Now that you mentioned it, I followed that code further and found another `_Is_duration` that takes a duration as a type. And value is set to true. So if the cast type matches that definition the value will be true. Otherwise it follows the code originally posted and is false.